# Moving cursor to next textbox automatically in UWP

Tags: c#, windows, uwp-xaml

I have 8 small textboxes with a maxlength of 1, and I want to make it so when somebody types a character in one of the boxes it automatically moves the cursor to the next box without the user having to press tab or manually click the next box in win 10 UWp
Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Please refer to: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And make the effort to complete the 2-minute site tour as well.

Answer (score 2):

> it automatically moves the cursor to the next box without the user having to press tab or manually click the next box in win 10 UWp Is there an easy way to do this?

The [Focus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702161) method would be that you want. Pass [FocusState.Keyboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.focusstate) as the parameter if you’re setting focus as a result of a keyboard interaction, like a tab sequence or key press.

I have made a simple code sample for your reference:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="50">
        <TextBox x:Name="txb1" MaxLength="1" Width="20" TextChanged="txb_TextChanged"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="txb2" MaxLength="1" Width="20" TextChanged="txb_TextChanged" Margin="10 0 0 0"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

```
private void txb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textbox = sender as TextBox;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text.Trim()))
    {
        txb2.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
    }
}
```

[image]